# Cardview in recyclerview showing grey and brown colors - android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've been stuck with the follow issue. I have a 'normal' card view with is showing up in funny different grey colours. I don't know why.
It looks like this:
[image]

Why isn't it the normal white?

Here is the xml for the item_row

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewItemName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the layout_content for the activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_choose"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.apps.reuven.choosepicture.ChoosePicturesToDisplayActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_choose_to_display">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewToDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>





    </RelativeLayout>
```

The theme in the manifest 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Which is...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Theme to this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I will when i can

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `Dark` theme `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` that's why your view background colors are showing darker.

Try using a `Light` theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the theme for in case you need white toolbar icons (Back arrow, title color, overflow menu icon), you can change this behavior in your theme.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
     <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>
 </style>
```